# How to sort address in a table using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having some trouble with sorting the addresses in my table. I would like to have them sort like this

```
800 E Maine Ave
801 E Maine Ave
802 E Maine Ave
7341 E Main St
7359 E Main St
7390 E Main St
```

but instead it is coming out like this

[image]

Here is the code I am using to sort the table. I have it when the caret is hit that it knows to sort by ascending or descending based on how it is pointed

```
function SetDataTable() {

    const tablerowsResult = document.querySelectorAll('#Resultbody tr'),
        tableheadingsResult = document.querySelectorAll('#ResultTable thead th.click');

    tableheadingsResult.forEach((head, i) => {
        let sortasc = true;
        head.onclick = () => {
            tableheadingsResult.forEach(head => head.classList.remove('active'));
            head.classList.add('active');

            document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => td.classList.remove('active'))
            tablerowsResult.forEach(row => {
                row.querySelectorAll('td')[i].classList.add('active')
            })

            head.classList.toggle('asc', sortasc);

            sortasc = head.classList.contains('asc') ? false : true;

            sortTableResult(i, sortasc);
        }
    })
}

function sortTableResult(col, sortasc) {
    const tablerowsResult = document.querySelectorAll('#Resultbody tr');

    [...tablerowsResult].sort((a, b) => {
        let firstrow = a.querySelectorAll('td')[col].textContent.toLowerCase();
        let secondrow = b.querySelectorAll('td')[col].textContent.toLowerCase();

        return sortasc ? (firstrow < secondrow ? 1 : -1) : (firstrow < secondrow ? -1 : 1);
    }).map(sortedrow => document.querySelector('#Resultbody').appendChild(sortedrow));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should sort rows the way you want:

```
function sortTableResult(col, sortasc) {
   const tablerowsResult = document.querySelectorAll('#Resultbody tr');

   [...tablerowsResult].sort((a, b) => {
      let firstrow = Number(a.querySelectorAll('td')[col].textContent.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0]);
      let secondrow = Number(b.querySelectorAll('td')[col].textContent.toLowerCase().split(' ')[0]);

      return sortasc ? (firstrow < secondrow ? 1 : -1) : (firstrow < secondrow ? -1 : 1);
   }).map(sortedrow => document.querySelector('#Resultbody').appendChild(sortedrow));
}
```

As I understand you want to sort addresses based on numeric values, so in this code I split the address with `.split(' ')` and then took first element, which is the one with a numeric value, and converted it to number.

Comment: I missed those closing brackets while formatting the code. Thanks for pointing it out.